# Last Modified By fields and foreign keys

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

In SQL Server 2012, I have a User table to store application users.  I also have an Organization table which has a LastModifiedBy field in which I would like to store the UserID of the last person to modify the values within the table via an ASPX page.  Should I create a foreign key relationship between the LastModifiedBy field and the UserID field within the Users table?

I would also like to add a LastModifiedBy field to the Users table itself.  Should/can I create a self referencing foreign key constraint on this table?  If this is possible, is it a horrible idea?

Any perspectives on pros and cons of creating these foreign key constraints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is what foreign keys are made for. These foreign keys are at the very core of relational databases. Even if they might give a slight performance impact when inserting new rows, because it has to check if the referenced key exists, it should not be avoided.